# Slice values of a column and calculate average in python

Tags: python, dataframe, time, slice

I have a dataframe with three columns:

```
a      b      c
0      73     12
73     80     2
80     100    5
100    150    13
```

Values in "a" and "b" are days. I need to find the average values of "c" in each 30 day-interval (slice values inside [min(a),max(b)] in 30 days and calculate average of c). I want as a result have a dataframe like this:

```
aa     bb     c_avg
0      30     12
30     60     12
60     90     6.33
90     120    9
120    150    13
```

Another sample data could be:

```
        a       b       c
    0   1264.0  1629.0  0.000000
    1   1629.0  1632.0  133.333333
    6   1632.0  1699.0  0.000000
    2   1699.0  1706.0  21.428571
    7   1706.0  1723.0  0.000000
    3   1723.0  1726.0  50.000000
    8   1726.0  1890.0  0.000000
    4   1890.0  1893.0  33.333333
    1   1893.0  1994.0  0.000000
```

How can I get to the final table?

Comment: Can you be more precise in your problem statement I will be happy to help you out?

Comment: I basically need to create new time-intervals from values between min(a) and max(b) and calculate average values of "c" when c is within the new intervals. Hope I could make it more clear.

Comment: Please share your attempt (code) to do this.

Comment: I wasn't able to tackle this at all! That's why here. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create ranges `DataFrame` by ranges defined `a` and `b` columns:

```
a = np.arange(0, 180, 30)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'aa':a[:-1], 'bb':a[1:]})
#print (df1)
```

Then cross join all rows by helper column `tmp`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1.assign(tmp=1), df.assign(tmp=1), on='tmp')
#print (df3)
```

And last filter - There are 2 solution by columns for filtering:

```
df4 = df3[df3['aa'].between(df3['a'], df3['b']) | df3['bb'].between(df3['a'], df3['b'])] 
print (df4)
     aa   bb  tmp    a    b   c
0     0   30    1    0   73  12
4    30   60    1    0   73  12
8    60   90    1    0   73  12
10   60   90    1   80  100   5
14   90  120    1   80  100   5
15   90  120    1  100  150  13
19  120  150    1  100  150  13

df4 = df4.groupby(['aa','bb'], as_index=False)['c'].mean()
print (df4)
    aa   bb     c
0    0   30  12.0
1   30   60  12.0
2   60   90   8.5
3   90  120   9.0
4  120  150  13.0
```

---

```
df5 = df3[df3['a'].between(df3['aa'], df3['bb']) | df3['b'].between(df3['aa'], df3['bb'])] 
print (df5)
     aa   bb  tmp    a    b   c
0     0   30    1    0   73  12
8    60   90    1    0   73  12
9    60   90    1   73   80   2
10   60   90    1   80  100   5
14   90  120    1   80  100   5
15   90  120    1  100  150  13
19  120  150    1  100  150  13

df5 = df5.groupby(['aa','bb'], as_index=False)['c'].mean()
print (df5)
    aa   bb          c
0    0   30  12.000000
1   60   90   6.333333
2   90  120   9.000000
3  120  150  13.000000
```

Comment: Oops! I think this is a bit different from what I need. For instance, the third row should return (12+2+5)/3 which is 6.3333 and the forth one should be (5+13)/2 which is 9, etc. Maybe I wasn't able to explain the problem clear enough! :-/

Comment: @geek2000 - sorry, please give me some time.

Comment: Thanks! This is awesome and works perfect on this data. But for some reasons I can't make it work on my original data. I got zero for all average values when getting at df4. I will play with it and will try to make it work! But will bother you if couldn't figure it out ;-) Thanks again for your great help!

Comment: @geek2000 - Hard question without data. But in my opinion is good test if numeric values in columns, `print (df.dtypes)`

Comment: Just checked. They are all floats! :-/ I will edit the question and add one sample of the original data. I don't know why this is not working!

Comment: Sorry, today and tmorrow I am offline, on phone ony. But I have idea, is possible send me data to my email from my profile if data not confidental ?

Comment: The data is unfortunately confidential and I am not allowed to share it. But what I maybe able to do is to de-identify a small portion of data and email it to you. Hope that works! Thank you for not giving up on this! :-)

Comment: Ok, please test if same problem with zeros like in real data, thanks.